# Equivalent definition of closure

Tags: general-topology

I keep seeing the closure of a set to be defined as follows:

> $\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Also, let $A\subseteq X$.
>
> > Then, $x\in cl(A)$ iff $\forall \epsilon>0$, $B(x;\epsilon)\cap A\neq \phi$ $\tag1$

I personally use the definition at the top shown below which I tagged as $(2)$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ How are these definitions equivalent (i.e. (1) and (2))?  Any help would be appreciated!

\begin{align}
x\in cl(A) \leftrightarrow \forall \text{ neighborhood } N \text{ of } x, N\cap A\neq \phi \tag2
\end{align}

Also, I use the following definition of a neighborhood: $N$ is a $\textbf{neighborhood}$ of $a$ given a metric space $(X, d)$ iff $\exists \delta\in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ ST $B(a;\delta)\subseteq N\subseteq X$.

Comment: I do not think they are equivalent. Example in $\mathbb R$ with standard metric, $S = (1,2)$, then $2 \in \mathrm {cl}(S)$, but none of neighborhood $B(2;r)$ is contained in $S$.

Comment: They are simply not equivalent.

Comment: Okay. What definition does everybody use then? I am surprised they aren't equivalent.

Comment: I am going to have to look back at this. I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: @W.G. $(1)$ seems a widely acceptable choice. If you like, you could change $B(x; \varepsilon)$ to "neighborhood" [although the latter might need some work to prove].

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I replace $B(x; \epsilon)$ from the first definition with some neighborhood $N$ of $\epsilon$: $N\cap A\neq \phi$ are they equivalent? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I figured my mistake. I am updating it now. I am sorry

Comment: $(2)$ is clearly not a definition of closure...  there are some different ways to do it...  for instance  $S\cup S'$, where $S'$ is the set of limit points (called the derived set, i think)

Comment: I switched it now.

Comment: Better.  That looks ok.

Comment: Okay good lol. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: In topology the definition of a neighborhood  of a point $p $ in a space $S$ is a set $N\subset S$ such that $ p\in U\subset N$ for some  open $U.$ In a metric space this is equivalent to the def'n you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your definition of neighborhood, every open ball centered at x is a neighborhood of x and every neighborhood of x contains an open ball centered at x.

Thus if every neighborhood of x intersects A then every open ball will intersect A and if every open ball centered at x intersects A, then every neighborhood of x intersects A because it contains an open ball centered at x.

Therefore these two definitions are equivalent.